# Centos7 Linux system hangs on boot

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, boot

Here's what I did:

```
sudo yum update
```

A kernel update was not in the list; basic stuff and video drivers (problem ?)

- dracut gave some error during update – do not recall specifics
- At this point, /boot was at that point 95%

To free space in /boot, I did:

```
package-cleanup –oldkernels –count=2
rm vmlinuz-0-rescue-* initramfs-0-rescue-*   # sort of regret this

grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

reboot   # just hangs (see pic)
```

I made a boot image, got into rescue mode and copied from backup the vmlinuz-0-rescue, initramfs-0-rescue images I had deleted. So, now I can boot into the rescue kernel, but not either of the two other full kernels I have.

[image]

Comment: It looks as if it's successfully loading a kernel, booting init, and starting services. If it's getting stuck on a particular service, consider booting into single user mode, disabling that service, and then rebooting and see if you get further. You can debug the problematic service once the system is up and you can log in.

Comment: I've gone through the services and disabled. No luck.